# Can i load data referenced by a Web Component dynamically, with caching?

Tags: html, caching, web-component, browser-cache

I'm currently learning Web Components and I wonder if it is possible to have a Component load its own data dynamically, similar to how `<img>` does from its `src` attribute, i.e. something like this:

```
<my-fancy-thingy src='/stuff.json'></my-fancy-thingy>
```

Obviously this functionality would be useful if `stuff.json` could be rather large, so it should also be possible to make use of the browser's caching mechanism so the referenced file doesn't get reloaded every time we request the page, unless changed.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, take inspiration from <load-file> See [Dev.to Post](https://dev.to/dannyengelman/load-file-web-component-add-external-content-to-the-dom-1nd)

```js
/*
  defining the <load-file> Web Component,
  
  yes! the documenation is longer than the code
  
  License: https://unlicense.org/

*/
customElements.define("load-file", class extends HTMLElement {

  // declare default connectedCallback as sync so await can be used
  async connectedCallback(
    // attach a shadowRoot if none exists (prevents displaying error when moving Nodes)
    // declare as parameter to save 4 Bytes: 'let '
    shadowRoot = this.shadowRoot || this.attachShadow({mode:"open"})
  ) {
      // load SVG file from src="" async, parse to text, add to shadowRoot.innerHTML
    shadowRoot.innerHTML = await (await fetch(this.getAttribute("src"))).text()

    // append optional <tag [shadowRoot]> Elements from inside <load-svg> after parsed <svg>
    shadowRoot.append(...this.querySelectorAll("[shadowRoot]"))

    // if "replaceWith" attribute 
    // then replace <load-svg> with loaded content <load-svg>
    // childNodes instead of children to include #textNodes also
    this.hasAttribute("replaceWith") && this.replaceWith(...shadowRoot.childNodes)
  }
})
```

Change `.text()` to `.json()` and it parses JSON files

Caching can be done by storing the String in localStorage (but a 5MB limit total, I think):

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_storage
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

You need to come up with "data has changed" strategy; as the Client has no clue when data actually *was* changed. Maybe an extra *semaphore* file/endpoint that provides info if the (large) JSON file **was** changed.

Comment: I was thinking more like reusing the browsers built-in chaching strategy somehow, i.e. the browser reuses its cached copy if the server sends a 304. But i guess its not possible for webcomponents so we have to reinvent the same thing using some method as you described.

Comment: Web Components are (Custom) HTML tags.. they have as much to do with *how* the Browser caches network requests as any other HTML tag... none.

Comment: Not sure what that is supposed to mean... are you saying that the 'fetch' function automatically reuses a browser-side-cached version of a file when appropriate like any other html-triggered file load? But why would I need to manually cache the results in localstorage then?

Comment: If your server sends the correct headers to allow caching, yes, then fetch will use the cached version. https://nitropack.io/blog/post/web-caching-beginners-guide and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Caching. All that has nothing to do with "Web Components"

Answer (score 1):

This works like a charm

```
export class MonElement extends HTMLElement                                                 {
    constructor(){ 
        super();
        this.attachShadow({mode:'open'}); 
        (...)
        this.shadowRoot.appendChild(atemplate);
    }
    connectedCallback(){...}
    static get observedAttributes(){
        return ['src'];
    }
    attributeChangedCallback(nameattr,oldval,newval)
    {
        if (nameattr==='src') {
            this[nameattr]=newval;
            here do the fetch for the src value which is newval then update what you got in the innerdom
    }
    (...)
```